# How can I get data from multiple table association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get data from multiple table in rails,but it is not working.

Here is my code.

Category.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

post.rb

```
has_many :mini_posts
belongs_to :category
```

mini_post.rb

```
belongs_to :post
```

controller

```
@posts = Category.find(params[:id]).posts.mini_posts
```

viewfile

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
    <%= post.description %>
  <% post.mini_posts.each do |mpost| %>
    <%= mpost.name %>
    <%= mpost.experience %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error shows "undefined method `mini_posts'.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is chaining methods, and returning mini posts, not eager loading the mini posts which is what I assume you want.

You want either

```
@posts = Post.includes(:mini_posts).where(category_id: params[:id])
```

Or

```
@category = Category.includes(posts: :mini_posts).find(params[:id])
@posts = @category.posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@posts = Category.find(params[:id]).posts.mini_posts
```

to

```
@posts = Category.find(params[:id]).posts
```

Comment: Would also recommend adding   .includes(:mini_posts) to the end of the change